# Simplify $(A - (A ∪ B)) ∩ (B - (A ∩ B))$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am trying to reduce $$(A - (A ∪ B)) ∩ (B - (A ∩ B)),$$ and I've made pretty good progress, but I get stuck after a certain point.  I'm wondering if what I've done thus far is correct, and whether I can continue to simplify this.

$(A - (A ∪ B)) ∩ (B - (A ∩ B))$

$= (A ∩ (A ∪ B)^c) ∩ (B ∩ (A ∩ B)^c)$   (Set Difference Law)

$= (A ∩ (A^c ∩ B^c)) ∩ (B ∩ (A^c ∪ B^c))$   (De Morgan’s Law)

$= ((A ∩ A^c) ∩ B^c) ∩ (B ∩ (A^c ∪ B^c))$   (Associative Laws)

$= ((A ∩ A^c) ∩ B^c) ∩ ((B ∩ A^c) ∪ (B ∩ B^c))$   (Distributive Laws)

$= (U^c ∩ B^c) ∩ ((B ∩ A^c) ∪ U^c)$   (Complements of $U$ and ∅)

Comment: Isn't this just $\varnothing$ because the left member is empty? $A$ is contained in $A\cup B$, so removing $A\cup B$ from $A$ removes all of $A$.

Comment: I think you're right, I'm just trying to figure out how I would simplify it using the various set identity laws.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression on the left is the set $A$ excluding the elements it shares with $A$ joined with $B$. That's the empty set. The empty set intersection with anything is the empty set.

With the reasons stated:

$(A-A\cup B))\cap (B-(A\cap B))$

$=(U^c\cap B^c)\cap((B\cap A^c)\cup U^c)~~~~~~~$ (By what you did above)

$=(\varnothing~\cap B^c)\cap ((B\cap A^c)\cup U^c)~~~~~~~~$ (Nothing is outside the set $U$)

$=\varnothing~\cap((B\cap A^c)\cup U^c)~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ ($\forall X,~\varnothing~\cap X=\varnothing$)

$=\varnothing~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~$ ($\forall X,~\varnothing~\cap X=\varnothing$)

I think those as reasons count as the "laws" you would be required to show for such a question.

Comment: Would you be willing to show the various set identity laws that prove this?  I'm not concerned about getting the correct answer, I want to understand how the different laws are applied.

Comment: @TK-421 Does what I did above count?